# Solve this equation with fixed point iteration

Tags: python, equation, nonlinear-functions, numerical-analysis, fixed-point-iteration

How can I solve this equation

> x<sup>3</sup> + x - 1 = 0

using fixed point iteration?

Is there any *fixed-point iteration* code (especially in Python) I can find online?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [scipy.optimize.fixed_point](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fixed_point.html#scipy-optimize-fixed-point):

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def func(x):
    return -x**3+1

# This finds the value of x such that func(x) = x, that is, where
# -x**3 + 1 = x
print(optimize.fixed_point(func,0))
# 0.682327803828
```

The Python code defining `fixed_point` is in scipy/optimize/minpack.py. The exact location depends on where `scipy` is installed. You can find that out by typing

```
In [63]: import scipy.optimize

In [64]: scipy.optimize
Out[64]: <module 'scipy.optimize' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.pyc'>
```

The current `fixed_point` source code can be found online by going to the [documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fixed_point.html#scipy-optimize-fixed-point) and clicking the `[source]` link.

Comment: Be warned if you pan to use the code snippet from this answer; the scipy 0.7.0 code for the scalar case contained a bug. The line  `if relerr < xtol:` should be `abs(relerr) < xtol`

Comment: @LenBlokken: Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) library. Here's a [relevant example](http://wiki.sympy.org/wiki/Quick_examples#Solve_a_polynomial_equation):

```
>>> solve(x**3 + 2*x**2 + 4*x + 8, x)
[-2*I, 2*I, -2]
```

I'm not sure which algorithm SymPy uses to solve the equation, though.