# Where's the bug in this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def sqrt(a):
    def tryit(x):
        return 0.5 * (a/x + x)
    return fixedPoint(tryit(x), 0.0001)
```

Comment: def sqrt(a):
    def tryit(x):
        return 0.5 * (a/x + x)
    return fixedPoint(tryit(x), 0.0001)

Comment: no the code has a little bug in itt. i can not add any extra line in it instead i am allowed to alter ant line in it.. the problem is in return statement.. please specify..

Comment: Is this an assignment you've got that you're now asking us to solve for you? Or is this your code and it's not working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

- You're calling `fixedPoint()` - what's that? Is this defined somewhere else?
- You're using `x` in the function without having defined it.
- You're calling the function `sqrt()`, but the logic isn't anywhere near something that would calculate the square root of anything.

There is at least one inelegance:

- You're defining a nested function (`tryit()`). This is not a problem per se, but it doesn't make much sense, and you're relying on a local variable `a` being defined here instead of passing that variable to a stand-alone function defined on the module level. It's hard to tell what that function is supposed to be doing, though.
- `tryit()` isn't a good function name.

Answer (score 0):

See [Solve this equation with fixed point iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326419) for working examples of fixed point iteration.

The code in the present question misspells `fixed_point`, a function that needs to be imported from `scipy.optimize`.  The required arguments of `fixed_point` include a function and an initial value; for example:

```
scipy.optimize.fixed_point(tryit, a/2)
```